# Tabla para gestionar descargas MySQL

Tags: mysql

estoy diseñando una base de datos para un proyecto personal a modo de práctica y no acabo de ver la manera de relacionar las tablas o qué campos necesito realmente. Mi idea es mostrar los libros más descargados y quizás que cada usuario pueda ver las descargas realizadas. Hasta el momento tengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué campos podría añadir para mejorar la tabla de descarga y así almacenar de manera correcta la cantidad de descargas que pueda tener un libro? Gracias

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Ya nos compartiste lo que estás haciendo, ahora bien: ¿cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: ¿A qué  te refieres con *la relación correctamente*?, ¿por qué crees que falta algo?, si aún a nivel de sentencias no has hecho algo mas, entonces mi mejor recomendación es que con papel y lápiz pruebes tu esquema y a partir de ahi salgan dudas mas concretas y asi evitar que luzca basada en opiniones

Comment: @BetaM creo que falta algo más en la tabla de descarga para poder mostrar los datos correctamente, no consigo ver si con la relación que tengo entre tablas sólo por sus ID bastaría. Al principio en la tabla libro tenía un campo llamado num_descargas que incrementaría cada vez que se realiza una descarga, pero de esa manera no lo relacionaría con los usuarios.

Comment: @muler2633 es que por ahi deberías partir, dices *para poder mostrar los datos correctamente*, entonces asumo que ya hiciste alguna prubea y obtuviste datos erróneos y entonces es sobre eso que debería versar tu pregunta, por ejemplo para mi hace falta una marca de tiempo para saber por ejemplo por día el libro o libros mas descargados pero eso es solo una opinión

Comment: @BetaM No, no hice ninguna prueba. Gracias por la opinión, cualquiera que ayude a mejorar es válida.

Comment: ¿Un usuario podría descargar el mismo libro más de una vez?

Comment: @DavidJP Sí, mientras que esté registrado, las veces que quiera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar registros duplicados y poder diferenciarlos (imagínate que sólo quieras borrar una de las descargas), deberías añadir un `id` o un timestamp, como te indica @BetaM, a la tabla `descarga`.

Pero vamos, aunque no lo hagas, simplemente agrupando en esa tabla, podrás obtener las estadísticas que comentas.

Libro más descargado:

```
SELECT id_libro,COUNT(*) n
    FROM descarga
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING COUNT(*)=(
    SELECT MAX(n) FROM (
        SELECT id_libro,COUNT(*) n
            FROM descarga
            GROUP BY 1  
      ) c1  
  );
```

Usuario que más descargas ha realizado:

```
SELECT id_usuario,COUNT(*) n
    FROM descarga
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING COUNT(*)=(
    SELECT MAX(n) FROM (
        SELECT id_usuario,COUNT(*) n
            FROM descarga
            GROUP BY 1  
      ) c1  
  );
```

Usuario que más ha descargado el mismo libro:

```
SELECT id_usuario,id_libro,COUNT(*) n
    FROM descarga
    GROUP BY 1,2
    HAVING COUNT(*)=(
    SELECT MAX(n) FROM (
        SELECT id_usuario,id_libro,COUNT(*) n
            FROM descarga
            GROUP BY 1,2  
      ) c1  
  );
```

Después combinas por cada `id` y sabrás a qué usuario y libro te estás refiriendo

Comment: Muchas gracias, he añadido tanto ID como timestamp, y así más sencillo añadir un apartado de descargas totales. Un saludo